# CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged += HandleConnectivityChanged Not Working in Xamarin forms + UWP

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

hello I am working on Xamarin forms. I have use Xam.Plugins.Connectivity Package but When I m call

CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged += HandleConnectivityChanged

void HandleConnectivityChanged(object sender, ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e)
{
}

It's Working in Android,ios,Windows phone device but it's not working UWP Desktop.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested your code and reproduced your issue. When I disconnected with `Ethernet`, the `HandleConnectivityChanged` method was not invoked.

[image]

And then I noticed that the network status icon displayed no internet access instead of Ethernet disconnection.

[image]

I checked the network connections and disable all the connections. The network state icon displayed no connection and the `HandleConnectivityChanged` was invoked.

[image]

So you could check if any other connection being displayed  when you disable the connection.